# Pass Redux state via NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, navigation, react-native, redux

I'm in the process of integrating Redux into a React Native app. I'm having trouble working out how to pass the Redux state via a NavigatorIOS component.

When execution enters the component shown below, the debugger shows

`props = Object {state: undefined, actions: Object}`

With the expected actions in the actions object, and state as yet undefined as it has not yet been initialised (I assume).

However when execution enters the ItemIndex component, the debugger shows

`props = Object {navigator: Object, route: Object}`

My current implementation tries to explicitly pass the state and actions but they are not pulled through: the debugger now shows

`props = Object {navigator: Object, route: Object, state: null, actions: undefined}`

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    const { actions, state } = props
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        ref = "nav"
        style = {styles.navigator}
        initialRoute = {{
          // Pass redux state into component
          passProps: { state: this.state, actions: this.actions },  
          // currently becomes { state: null, actions: undefined }
          title: 'Items',
          component: ItemIndex
        }}/> 
    )
  }
}

module.exports = MainComponent
```

Is there a way I can continue to pass the Redux state down via `NavigatorIOS`?

Comment: What about injecting them as props to the initialRoute? I know that may not gel with how your app is structured, but it is one way.

Comment: @NaderDabit Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) supports Redux, uses native iOS view controllers (via [react-native-controllers](https://github.com/wix/react-native-controllers) instead of navigatorIOS) and will soon support Android. This has so far been the best navigation solution for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was leaving out the `props` part of the chain:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        ref = "nav"
        style = {styles.navigator}
        initialRoute = {{
          // Pass redux state into component
          passProps: { state: this.props.state, actions: this.props.actions },  
          title: 'Items',
          component: ItemIndex
        }}/> 
    )
  }
```

Actually - this only works for the initial state, it seems to stop the state change triggering component updates for the initialRoute component and subsequent components.

Comment: No solution?  I have a <TabBarIOS> with 3 tabs.  I added display of a state all around to try to understand what is wrong. The <TabBariOS> tab bar updates. Views inside <Icon.TabBarItem> updates.  The only thing that does not update is a <Icon.TabBarItem> containing a <NavigatorIOS> <ListView>.  I can call an action to change state from <NavigatorIOS> <ListView> and everybody updates except <NavigatorIOS> views.  Does <NavigatorIOS> not work when passing redux state using passProps?

Comment: In summary using passProps to pass redux state to <NavigatorIOS> never update when state changes.  Other components update fine?